# Does Thread.sleep(n) in Android runs new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a tricky question about threads on which I am unable to find answer. The thing is that I need to make dummy app, with splashscreen on for 2 sec, and after it, the new activity is started. The user can stop this waiting process by pressing back arrow and then splashscreen should be closed and second window should not be opened.

What I came up with is `AsyncTakk` where in doInBackround is `Thread.sleep(2000)` and in `onPostExecute()` new app is opened. Also I have cancellation of this asynctask in `onPause`.

So the doInBackground looks like that:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I think that this is correct approach. According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

> Causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given
>   interval of time (given in milliseconds). The precision is not
>   guaranteed - the Thread may sleep more or less than requested.

For me it seems ok.

However, I've got info from person checking it, that I'm starting new thread there and **this is a mistake**.

I've added strict mode check in it and nothing. Checked also threads in eclipse, and also I don't see anything unusual.

So, my question is - do I really make new thread and why, and if not, can you provide some links, to show him that.

Comment: No need for links, just read the documentation!  You could also use a little logic.  If Thread.Sleep started a new thread, then how could it pause the current one? What work is done on this "new" thread?  How could you control it?  Thread.sleep does not create a new thread.  Your friend is wrong. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: I am aware of that, but he is not I guess. This is why I asked for links.

Comment: As I say, you don't need links.  Just show him the documentation - I even gave you the URL!

Comment: ... and ask *him* for *his* citation and *his* evidence. It's his crackpot theory.

Comment: Your 'checking person' has the OS/multithreading knowledge of a pavement slab.

Answer (score 0):

The new thread is not created by `sleep()`. A new thread might be created created by `AsyncTask.execute()`. The method `doInBackground()` is executed in a 'background' thread, not in the main thread. `AsyncTask.execute()` doesn't have to create a new thread. It can reuse an existing 'background' thread from a pool of threads that it uses internally.
Your solution is not wrong(actually some might consider it wrong because it may create an unnecessary thread), but there is a better one. You should use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`.

```
// call from main thread
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(r, 2000); 
// the runnable r will contain the code that has to execute in 2000 milliseconds
```

Comment: But as far as I know, only `AsyncTask` can provide mechanism for action after execution. And this is what I need. So handler is not for me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'action after execution'. I am pretty sure that you can solve your problem using handlers. You can remove the queued Runnable using Handler.removeCallback(Runnable r).